# Infinite loop when fetching data with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use hooks, but am in an infinite loop.  The code is below.  fetchSomeData and uuid get passed in from the parent component. The data that is fetched is the same every time.  Thanks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [myList, setMyList] = useState([]);

  const {fetchSomeData, uuid} = props;

  fetchSomeData(uuid)
    .then( (response) => {
      setMyList(response.payload.data.activities);
  })

  const renderItem = (item)=>{
    return (<div>{item.title}</div>)
  }

  return (
    <div> My COmponent 
      <div>
        {myList.map (renderItem)}
      </div>      
    </div>      
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cause you're executing the fetcher function on each render, updating the state and triggering a new render, which fetches data again and so on...

Wrap your imperative code with an `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() =>{
    fetchSomeData(uuid)
        .then( (response) => {
            setMyList(response.payload.data.activities);
    })
},[uuid])
```

Now you're only fetching when `uuid` changes